# This tag is kind of [fuzzy]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The tag wiki for [fuzzy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fuzzy) says

> Do not use this tag. It is ambiguous: see fuzzy-search, fuzzy-logic,
>   or image-processing for more appropriate tags.

If the wiki says not to use it then shouldn't we do as it says?

Comment: Because mods don't like burninating tags for whatever reason (I've yet to hear of a good one).

Comment: And while you're at it, get rid of [fuzzy-comparison].

Comment: You should first close and delete all the necessary questions using that tag to help clean the site up, not just getting rid of tags wholesale

Comment: @random fair point.  I've started going through them and flagging/editing as appropriate

Comment: *checks user reputation*... yep @random, can't do

Comment: The wiki can be changed. Also it seems there might be a [product/technology called Fuzzy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24520370/109702)?

Comment: @slugster while I'm not certain, I think Fuzzy K-Means is referring to a statistical technique/formula/something (not a programming concept/library/language/something).  The wiki could certainly be changed - do you have suggestions/ideas?  Wouldn't more specific tags be preferred (and easier to be an expert in)?

Comment: @Dannnno I would suggest that `fuzzy` isn't being drastically misused (ignoring the wiki description), and it's probably not worth splitting it into more specific tags - unless there are established names for specific "fuzzy" algorithms.

Comment: IMO, most/all adjective tags are evil, because they don't refer to anything concrete. This is a perfect example.

Comment: Perhaps having that tag with the warning serves the purpose of encouraging people not to use it, while pointing to more relevant, related tags

Comment: @Qix destroying all the crap meta tags would make it harder to get a Copy Editor badge.  It's not like there's a robo-edit problem for the mods to be concerned about. /facepalm

Comment: Would you say that you're fuzzy about the point of this tag?

Answer (score -3):

Having a tag that shouldn't be used serves at least two purposes:

- **Warns people not to use that tag**. We all know many people carelessly type in any word they think is relevant, and use that as a tag. If that word is *not* a tag, nothing happens. But if that word *is* a tag, its description appears immediately below. So the user will be informed by the description (assuming they read it) that the tag shouldn't be used.
- That description also **points to other related, more relevant tags** that *should* be used.

Comment: Wouldn't having several other, more specific, tags that start with 'fuzzy' be an alternative though?  They pop up as suggestions as you're typing it in.  And we all know that people don't read tag wikis

Comment: @Dannnno I don't see that as an alternative, but rather as a _complement_

Comment: -1, burninating a tag usually blacklists it. When you type in `fuzzy` you'll get all of the tags you *should* be using.

Comment: @Qix What does "blacklist" exactly mean here? I mean, does that _prevent_ the user from using that word as if it were a tag? If not, the first item in my answer would still apply

Comment: I mean an error message appears saying you cannot re-create the tag.

Comment: @Qix: Very few tags are ever blacklisted, as that's a dev-only option for egregiously bad tags which people just recreate *all the time*.